# Retrofit2 encodes Query value even when encoded=true

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2

Using Retrofit 2.4, I'm calling an API that receives a JSON object as part of a query string such as /list?filter={"columns":"a,b,c","start":""...}

Instead of writing a converter I just use a jackson mapper to write the object as string before.

```
fun getReport(@Query("filter", encoded = true) request: String)
```

But what retrofit is doing is that it does not encode the brackets, but it does encode all the quotes, the url then becomes:

filter={%22columns%22: ...

And this is of course causing issues with the invocation.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use QueryMap in your functions

```
@QueryMap(encodeNames = true)
```

more details refer [Annotation Type QueryMap](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/QueryMap.html)

Comment: I tried that and also does not work. Added a QueryMap, with a map: "filter" : JsonString, and it also escapes quotes